# NetBeans IDE - how to run Java application with console

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line-arguments

I am just wondering is there a way in NetBeans to start Java application with console arguments (I mean the default ones input for main method)? I mean the effect like when you run your app with Command Prompt manually:

```
>MyTestApp arg0 arg1 argN
```

I couldn't find the IDE feature  so I need your advice. Is there a way to run apps with NetBeans in that way?

P.S.
NetBeans 6.5.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on your project's name and select "Properties" from the menu. One of the tabs in that window lets you set command-line arguments. I don't recall the exact one off the top of my head.

Comment: In the new versions of Netbeans this option in properties is no longer available.

Comment: I have some projects that have the run property, and others that do not.  I'm currently running NB 8.2.

Comment: @RichardJessop If you have a question, please click on the "Ask a question" button at the top right of any page on this site.

Answer (score 2):

After you build the project Netbeans will show you the build results in the output pane.
simply copy the last line that indicates the location of the main jar file executable, for example:

`java -jar /home/abusada/NetBeansProjects/userInput/dist/userInput.jar`

start your terminal on Linux or console on Windows and paste the above.

Hit enter to run your file.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to `Run Configurations...` and set your VM Settings there. It should be passed on to the console when it runs.

Comment: Thanks for further steps tips :)